# Android on Blackberry development with IntelliJ

Tags: android, blackberry, intellij-idea

I have an Android app that needs to be ported to Blackberry, using the Blackberry APK repackaging tools.  From what I can tell there's a plugin for Eclipse that supports this, however I use IntelliJ for Android development, and I really don't want to go back to Eclipse.

Is it possible to setup IntelliJ in such a way that I can do the full build/run/debug cycle for Android on Blackberry apps.  If so, where can I find detailed instructions on how to set this up.

If not, what's the next best alternative.

*To be clear, I'm not talking about "Android development with IntelliJ", nor "Blackberry development with IntelliJ".  I'm specifically after information for "Android on Blackberry development with IntelliJ"*

Comment: I can use Command Line Tools. http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/preparing_android_apps_for_bbtos_1729415_11.html